# Is it wrong to use the words Namaz, Khuda, Roza?

Tags: terminology

I am from Bangladesh. Here almost everyone exclusively use the word Namaz to refer  to Salat. Recently my parents have been pressuring me to use the word Salat in place of Namaz. Their argument goes like this. Namaz is supposedly a word that was used by Zoroastrians to refer to their prayers. Similarly Khuda is a word that was used by Zoroastrians to refer to their god. So we should not use these words. I searched the internet but did not find much supporting these claims. My question is even if these claims are true   would using these words be wrong?

Comment: That is exactly my question. Does it matter that the words we use be in Arabic? What is the criteria here?

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem using such teminologies in your own language.